# Will excessive steps during training mess up the training process in Machine Learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a dataset of 3372149 rows, and I batch them every 3751 rows as the code shown below:

```
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
  x={"x": train_features_numpy},
  y=train_labels_numpy,
  batch_size = 3751,
  num_epochs= 1,
  shuffle=False)

  # Train
  nn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)#, steps=10000)
```

If I set num_epochs = 1 as what I have in the code, it means that the training process would go through the dataset once right? And that leads to the total steps equals to 3372149/3751 = 899.

If I uncomment the "steps = 10000" part, and set "num_epochs=none", the training part would be forced to train all the way to step 10000.

I have two questions then:

1. Since I only have 899 sets of valid data but I set the step to 10000, what is Tensorflow training after step 899? Does it just go back to the top and repeat the training?
2. If I trained more then 899 steps, is it going to mess up the model that relates the features and labels? Or is it redundant since the training loop just go over and over the same data set?

I did ask about the loss not reduced during training in my other posts and I am now thinking if I have too few data sets to train on and thus all the excessive steps are useless.

Comment: What could re-training with the same data achieve - except for over fitting?

Comment: I am not sure more steps than datasets is doing re-training or not. If so, we don't want to waste time on doing the same stuff again and again right? Unless there is some beneficial part here, that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over a dataset many times is quite common and normal. Each "step" of your model (that is each batch) takes one gradient update step. In intuitive terms it has taken one step towards the goal in the direction dictated by that mini batch. It does NOT learn everything it can about a particular sample by seeing it once, it just takes a step closer to the goal, and how big a step is dictated by the learning rate (and other more complex factors). If you cut your learning rate in half you'd need twice as many steps to get there. Notice how that had nothing to do with epochs, just "update steps" (aka batches).

The typical way of knowing when it's time to stop is to plot test data accuracy over time as you train your model. It is certainly possible that your model will begin to overfit at some point. If it does so test accuracy will start to get worse, this is an obvious optimal stopping point.

Also note that batches of data are not sequential, each batch is randomly selected by permuting the data. The next time through the dataset will end up with different batches of data, and thus each of these batches will produce a different gradient update. So even going through the dataset twice will not produce the same set of updates on each epoch.

I don't actually know the answer to question #1 because I don't use the estimator API much, but I'm 90% sure it simply permutes the samples and iterates through them again after each epoch. That's the most common approach.

Comment: "Also note that batches of data are not sequential, each batch is randomly selected by permuting the data." Is this refer to shuffling? In my case, it is okay to shuffle the batches but I don't want to shuffle the data inside a batch.

Comment: I do mean shuffling, yes, which is occurring every epoch in most implementations and I presume as well in the estimator API. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by not wanting to shuffle within a batch. Unless this is an RNN (in which case timesteps are not shuffled), your data is considered IID and each batch will be randomly permuted. I suppose you could disable this, but you should really understand why you're doing so if you want to do that because it would be quite abnormal.

Comment: Since I intentionally make my data meaningful every 3751 rows, I want the flow to take in 3751 rows every time. That's why I set the batch_size to be 3751. Will it randomly pick 3751 rows of my data as a batch? Or it take the data in orders?

Comment: What kind of model is this? If it's not an RNN, RL, or other time series model, then the model is most likely assuming IID and will not perform well under these assumptions. If your data is sequential you should probably look into an RNN, in which case you'll be modeling your dataset such that one sample is 3751 "timesteps". There is no sequence to a batch, each sample of a batch is independently computed and the gradients are simply averaged at the end.

Comment: Do you mind to take a look at my other post here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380844/tensorflow-not-predicting-accurate-enough-results)

I explained what I am trying to do more specifically in this post. Thanks

Comment: That looks like a 16 step sequence model (aka time series) to me, if I'm reading it correctly. You say you have millions of those 16x10 sets of values that you show in the spreadsheet there right? And that there's a progression from line 2 to line 17 right? I see current in the last column that seems to suggest a progression from 2 to 17. The order of the sequence matters right? If everything I said is correct, then you need an RNN, not a fully connected network. Here are my favorite tutorials on the subject: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples

Comment: it is actually every 3751 rows forms a meaningful input. The inputs forms something like a 3D plot (31*11*11) with the 'current' being the data stored in the coordinates. Every 3751 rows of inputs correspond to 1 set of output (with 6 columns). And yes the sequence matter.

Comment: Definitely RNNs then, your current model will perform quite poorly because it can't account for sequences (batching strategy does NOT accomplish this). I suggest reading up on them and looking at the tutorials, then post a separate question about structuring your data for an RNN to clarify anything that isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks David! One final question before I jump into RNN. I've briefly looked into the tutorial and saw that the MNIST example is using RNN to classify things. My case, however, is to train a model between four features and six lables; not exactly classifying. Do you think RNN can do this?

Comment: The output of an RNN is exactly the same as you are using here. The input needs to be structured as a sequence, so that changes. The use of MNIST is a nice example to demonstrate that things you might not associated with RNNs (an image in this case) can indeed be modeled with RNNs. Check out Colah's blog also: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/